# C++ using recursion find the number of nonzeros in a Vector

Tags: c++, recursion

EDIT
I got this code to work with an array, but I cant get it to work with a vector, does anyone know how I can change it from using an array to a vector?

```
int count(double* arr, int length);

int main() 
{
double arr[10] = {0.0, 1.3, 2.5, 11.34, 0.0, 9.8, 6.4, 0.0, 4.3, 0.0};

cout << "There are " << count(arr, 10) << " nonzeros in this array!\n\n";

return 0;
}

int count(double* arr, int length) 
{
if (!length)
{
    return 0;
}

int c = count(arr+1, length-1);

return arr[0] != 0.0 ? c + 1 : c;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You loop `while (i < s)` will never exit, as you don't modify either `i` nor `s` in the loop.

You can actually make the function a little simpler, first of all by not having a loop (that's what the recursion is for), then realizing you only need the size and the current index as arguments. Then you could make it like

```
int nonzeroes(double* digits, size_t size, size_t index)
{
    if (index < size)
    {
        return (digits[index] != 0.0) + nonzeroes(digits, size, index + 1);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

This works because boolean values can be implicitly converted to `int`, with `true` being `1` and `false` being `0`. It then adds the returned value of the next index which is fetched by using the recursive call.

The initial call from your `main` function should be like

```
nonzeroes(digits, s, 0)
```

That starts the counting using index zero.

I recommend you use a debugger to step through the code line by line, while entering the recursive calls to see how it works.

---

On a side-note, if you want a dynamic array in C++, you should be using [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector).

On another side-note, for simple cases like yours comparing to `0.0` will work, but if you create the values through other algorithms or arithmetic then there will be compounded rounding errors which means the value might be *close* but not completely equal to zero. This could be solved by using an *epsilon* value, for example by using [`std::numeric_limits<double>::epsilon`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/numeric_limits/epsilon).

Answer (score 0):

I may be wrong but to use recursion you need a base case, to stop the calls, and i don't think you need to pass count either.

I think one option could be this:

```
int nonzeros(double digits[], int s, int i)
{
    if (i == s)
    {   
        return 0;
    }
    else if (digits[i] != 0.0)
    {
        return  (1 + nonzeros(digits, s, i + 1));
    }
    else
    {
        return (nonzeros(digits, s, i + 1));
    }
}
```